# Count items bigger than 2 in a list

Tags: prolog

I have a List with numbers. (e.g : **L = [1,0,0,1,3,2,3]**).

I'm trying to create a predicate which takes this list and returns an integer E, which is the times of occurrences of any number bigger than 2.

For instance in the case above let's say that the predicate is called **pred/2**,
then **pred([1,0,0,1,3,2,3],E)** would return **E = 2** because the only number bigger than 2 is 3 and this number occurs 2 times.

In the case that there are 2 and more different numbers bigger than 2, for instance: **L = [0,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6]** would have to return 5 because there are 5 numbers that are bigger than 2.

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

We can use a helper predicate with accumulator **count/3**. We will use this accumulator store count of already encountered values greater than 2.

```
% we initialize accumulator with 0
count(L, Count) :- count2(L, 0, Count).

% for empty list there is no more elements grater than 2
count2([], Acum, Acum).

% otherwise we have two consider two cases
count2([H|T], Acum, Out) :-
( H > 2 ->
    Acum2 is Acum + 1,
    count2(T, Acum2, Out)
;
    count2(T, Acum, Out)
).
```

Comment: Why would you need an accumulator?

Comment: If you're wondering, you can achieve the same with `count([], 0).
count([X|Xs], C) :- count(Xs, C1), (X>2 -> C is C1+1 ; C=C1).`

Comment: @fferri agreed. Didn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the best way to go is to write some modern prolog using high-order predicates:

```
pred(List, Count) :-
    maplist([In,Out] >> (In>2 -> Out=1 ; Out=0), List, BinaryList),
    foldl([In1,In2,Out] >> (Out is In1+In2), BinaryList, 0, Count).
```

which works by mapping each item to 1 if it is greater than 2, otherwise to 0, and then summing the 1s and 0s.

Some tests:

```
?- pred([1,0,0,1,3,2,3], Count).
Count = 2.

?- pred([0,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6], Count).
Count = 5.
```

---

Bonus: this can be generalized to counting how many elements make a predicate hold:

```
count(Pred, List, Count) :-
    maplist([In,Out] >> (call(Pred,In) -> Out=1 ; Out=0), List, BinaryList),
    foldl([In1,In2,Out] >> (Out is In1+In2), BinaryList, 0, Count).
```

so that we can pass the `(X>2)` as an argument:

```
?- count([X] >> (X>2), [1,0,0,1,3,2,3], Count).
Count = 2.
```

or something else:

```
?- count([X] >> (X<2), [1,0,0,1,3,2,3], Count).
Count = 4.
```